# Docker build is installing unnecessary packages causing image to fail running

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, .net-core

I'm working on a dotnet core project using docker and amazon EC2 instance (local machine is a mac).

Everything was working fine till today.
On my last docker build, the command dotnet restore starts installing new and necessary packages.
It should install only 65 packages and now I get more than a hundred.
Moreover, the image generated by docker has grown from 500Mo to 850Mo with no reason.

Do you have any clue where it might come from.

My full install :

- Mac OS El Capitan
- Visual Code 1.17.2
- .net core 1.1
- Docker
- Amazon EC2 Instance

------ Edit : More infos ---------

My csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity" Version="3.3.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.3.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup" Version="3.3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.3.5.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="SSH.Net" Version="2016.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ImageSharp" Version="1.0.0-alpha9-00089" />
    <PackageReference Include="ImageSharp.Drawing" Version="1.0.0-alpha9-00084" />
    <PackageReference Include="iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="1.16.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Mailjet.Api" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Json" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Certes" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The Docker File :

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

And here are all the packages installed by dotnet restore command. Some packages are installed twice in two different versions. Strange also to have some ubuntu or Apple SSL package that weren't installed before :

```
  Installing System.Text.Encodings.Web 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Net.WebSockets 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel 4.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor 1.1.1.
  Installing System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.1.3.
  Installing Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 1.1.1.
  Installing AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity 3.3.2.6.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities 1.0.0.
  Installing AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup 3.3.0.3.
  Installing Mailjet.Api 1.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 1.0.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Serialization.Json 4.3.0.
  Installing AWSSDK.S3 3.3.5.14.
  Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens 5.1.3.
  Installing System.Collections.Immutable 1.2.0.
  Installing ImageSharp 1.0.0-alpha9-00140.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 1.1.1.
  Installing SSH.NET 2016.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https 1.0.1.
  Installing AWSSDK.Core 3.3.13.1.
  Installing MailKit 1.16.1.
  Installing Certes 1.1.0.
  Installing Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 1.1.0.
  Installing iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core 1.3.2.
  Installing ImageSharp.Drawing 1.0.0-alpha9-00135.
  Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0.
  Installing AWSSDK.SecurityToken 3.3.1.5.
  Installing System.Net.WebSockets 4.3.0.
  Installing System.ComponentModel.Primitives 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 1.1.1.
  Installing NETStandard.Library 1.6.1.
  Installing Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal 1.1.1.
  Installing System.IO 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.1.
  Installing System.Runtime 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions 1.1.2.
  Installing System.Private.DataContractSerialization 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing System.Collections 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Extensions 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Globalization.CultureInfoCache 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing System.Runtime.InteropServices 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Security.Claims 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Text.RegularExpressions 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Threading 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging 1.1.3.
  Installing System.Buffers 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Numerics.Vectors 4.3.0.
  Installing System.IO.Compression 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.4.0-preview1-25305-02.
  Installing System.Memory 4.4.0-preview1-25305-02.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect 2.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.TraceSource 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Globalization 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.0.11.
  Installing System.IO 4.1.0.
  Installing System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1.
  Installing System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Linq 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Reflection.Extensions 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Threading.Thread 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.0.10.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.2.0.
  Installing System.Text.RegularExpressions 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Timer 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Threading 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Extensions 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Xml.XPath.XDocument 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Xml.XmlDocument 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1.
  Installing SshNet.Security.Cryptography 1.2.0.
  Installing System.Net.NameResolution 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Net.Security 4.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 1.0.1.
  Installing System.Collections 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Console 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Collections.NonGeneric 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Net.Http 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Reflection.TypeExtensions 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.InteropServices 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Csp 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Text.Encoding.Extensions 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Xml.XDocument 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Net.Requests 4.0.11.
  Installing System.ValueTuple 4.3.1.
  Installing Portable.BouncyCastle 1.8.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo 4.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 1.1.0.
  Installing Npgsql 3.1.9.
  Installing System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Reflection.TypeExtensions 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Globalization.Extensions 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Net.NameResolution 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Net.Security 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Data.Common 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Net.NetworkInformation 4.3.0.
  Installing MimeKit 1.16.1.
  Installing System.Collections.NonGeneric 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Net.Requests 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Loader 4.3.0.
  Installing CoreCompat.System.Drawing 1.0.0-beta006.
  Installing System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 1.1.1.
  Installing System.Xml.XmlDocument 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Data.SqlClient 4.3.0.
  Installing SixLabors.Shapes.Text 0.1.0-alpha0017.
  Installing Libuv 1.9.1.
  Installing Microsoft.CSharp 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR 1.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.VisualBasic 10.1.0.
  Installing System.Collections.Immutable 1.3.0.
  Installing System.ComponentModel 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Dynamic.Runtime 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Linq.Parallel 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Linq.Expressions 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Reflection.Metadata 1.4.1.
  Installing System.Resources.Reader 4.3.0.
  Installing System.AppContext 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.3.0.
  Installing System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy 1.1.2.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.3.1.
  Installing System.Linq.Queryable 4.3.0.
  Installing System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles 4.3.0.
  Installing System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Net.Http 4.3.2.
  Installing System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Reflection.DispatchProxy 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Net.WebHeaderCollection 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Process 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow 4.7.0.
  Installing System.Net.Security 4.3.1.
  Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic 1.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization 1.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native 1.4.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 1.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors 1.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer 1.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations 1.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json 1.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 1.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 1.0.0.
  Installing System.Linq.Expressions 4.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 1.1.2.
  Installing System.Reflection 4.1.0.
  Installing System.ComponentModel 4.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.3.0.
  Installing System.AppContext 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Collections.Concurrent 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Console 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Globalization 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Tracing 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Globalization.Calendars 4.3.0.
  Installing System.IO.Compression.ZipFile 4.3.0.
  Installing System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0.
  Installing System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Linq 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Net.Http 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Net.Primitives 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0.
  Installing System.ObjectModel 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 1.1.0.
  Installing System.Reflection.Extensions 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Reflection 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Reflection.Primitives 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Handles 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Numerics 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHost 1.1.0.
  Installing System.Text.Encoding 4.3.0.
  Installing System.ObjectModel 4.0.12.
  Installing System.Runtime 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Text.Encoding 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Threading.Timer 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Text.Encoding.Extensions 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Xml.XDocument 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives 4.1.1.
  Installing System.Dynamic.Runtime 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Collections.Immutable 1.3.1.
  Installing Remotion.Linq 2.1.1.
  Installing System.Interactive.Async 3.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.1.0.
  Installing System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Xml.XmlSerializer 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Security.Principal 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.Apple 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.native.System 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Net.Http 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Cng 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Csp 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.win7-x86.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.native.System.IO.Compression 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Options 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions 1.1.1.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.StackTrace 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing runtime.win7-x64.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 1.1.1.
  Installing System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols 2.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection 1.1.1.
  Installing System.Reflection.Primitives 4.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.0.1.
  Installing runtime.native.System 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Net.Primitives 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Numerics 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1.
  Installing System.ComponentModel.Primitives 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Tracing 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.0.1.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Net.Security 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Collections.Concurrent 4.0.12.
  Installing System.Globalization.Extensions 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Security.Claims 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Security.Principal 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Buffers 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 1.0.0.
  Installing System.Numerics.Vectors 4.1.1.
  Installing Libuv 1.9.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting 1.0.0.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Net.Http 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Net.WebHeaderCollection 4.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 1.1.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Contracts 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Data.Common 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Net.NetworkInformation 4.1.0.
  Installing System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Overlapped 4.0.1.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Net.Security 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Overlapped 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Collections.Specialized 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Drawing.Primitives 4.0.0.
  Installing System.IO.Pipes 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.3.0.
  Installing SixLabors.Fonts 0.1.0-alpha0011.
  Installing SixLabors.Shapes 0.1.0-alpha0017.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Windows.ApiSets 1.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Jit 1.1.2.
  Installing System.Reflection.Emit 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostResolver 1.1.0.
  Installing runtime.opensuse.13.2-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
  Installing runtime.ubuntu.16.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
  Installing runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Win32.Registry 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.rhel.7-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
  Installing runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
  Installing runtime.fedora.24-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
  Installing runtime.osx.10.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
  Installing runtime.ubuntu.14.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
  Installing runtime.fedora.23-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
  Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.1.2.
  Installing runtime.opensuse.42.1-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Host 1.1.2.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Localization 1.1.1.
  Installing System.Reflection.Emit 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight 4.0.1.
  Installing runtime.osx.10.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.Apple 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.fedora.23-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite 1.1.0.
  Installing runtime.opensuse.13.2-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.opensuse.42.1-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.fedora.24-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.osx.10.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.rhel.7-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.ubuntu.14.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing runtime.ubuntu.16.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0.
  Installing System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing System.Text.Encodings.Web 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 1.1.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 1.1.1.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Contracts 4.3.0.
  Installing System.Collections.Specialized 4.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions 1.1.1.
  Installing System.Globalization.Calendars 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Cng 4.2.0.
  Installing System.Reflection.Metadata 1.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Options 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.0.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.StackTrace 4.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 1.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 1.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Options 1.1.0.
```

Many thanks !

Comment: Can you add some details about your dependencies, what was being installed before and now.

Comment: Hard to tell without at least your `Dockerfile`, but maybe a package updated and has new requirements?

Comment: I had some addtional infos. Maybe it's due to a change to microsoft/dotnet latest image ?